# TYPO3 Neos: Create route throws exception

Tags: typo3, typo3-flow, neoscms

I want to crate an inspector editor which loads data from the repository, and do the same like TYPO3.Neos do. TYPO3 Neos v1.2.0-beta2

I created a template which render an relation link:

```
<f:security.ifAccess resource="Vendor_Package_BackendAccess">
    <link rel="vendor-data" href="{f:uri.action( package: 'Vendor.Package', controller: 'Backend\Content', action: 'load absolute: true )}" />
</f:security.ifAccess>
```

This is rendered like `TYPO3.Neos:Page.head.neosBackendEndpoints`

But with and without following routes settings it throws following exception:

> Could not resolve a route and its corresponding URI for the given
>   parameters. This may be due to referring to a not existing package /
>   controller / action while building a link or URI. Refer to log and
>   check the backtrace for more details. (20141211101038f2dcd5)

Routes.yaml:

```
#                                                                        #
# Default subroutes configuration for the Vendor.Package package.    #
#                                                                        #


-
  name: 'Content Controller - Load data'
  uriPattern: 'vendor/package'
  defaults:
    '@package': 'Vendor.Package'
    '@controller': 'Backend\Content'
    '@action': 'load
```

And the controller exists:

Packages/Application/Vendor.Package/Classes/Vendor/Package/Controller/Backend/ContentController.php

Here the log:

```
Uncaught exception #1301610453: Could not resolve a route and its corresponding URI for the given parameters. This may be due to referring to a not existing package / controller / action while building a link or URI. Refer to log and check the backtrace for more details.

51 TYPO3\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Uri\ActionViewHelper_Original::render("load", array|0|, "Backend\Content", "Vendor.Package", NULL, "", "", array|0|, TRUE, FALSE, array|0|, FALSE)
50 call_user_func_array(array|2|, array|12|)
49 TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper::callRenderMethod()
48 TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper::initializeArgumentsAndRender()
47 FluidCache_Standalone_template_file_BackendEndpoints_036fbf06ab45ee579de56d2cae3e675dedf18c2d::{closure}()
46 TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper::renderChildren()
45 TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractConditionViewHelper::renderThenChild()
44 TYPO3\Fluid\ViewHelpers\Security\IfAccessViewHelper_Original::render("Vendor_Package_BackendAccess")
43 call_user_func_array(array|2|, array|1|)
42 TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper::callRenderMethod()
41 TYPO3\Fluid\Core\ViewHelper\AbstractViewHelper::initializeArgumentsAndRender()
40 FluidCache_Standalone_template_file_BackendEndpoints_036fbf06ab45ee579de56d2cae3e675dedf18c2d::render(TYPO3\Fluid\Core\Rendering\RenderingContext)
39 TYPO3\Fluid\View\AbstractTemplateView::render()
38 TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\TemplateImplementation_Original::evaluate()
37 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::evaluateInternal("landingPage<TYPO3.Neos:Page>/head<TYPO3.TypoScript:Array>/BackendEndpoints", "NULL", TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\ArrayImplementation)
36 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::evaluate("landingPage<TYPO3.Neos:Page>/head<TYPO3.TypoScript:Array>/BackendEndpoints", TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\ArrayImplementation)
35 TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\AbstractTypoScriptObject::tsValue("BackendEndpoints")
34 TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\ArrayImplementation_Original::evaluate()
33 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::evaluateInternal("landingPage<TYPO3.Neos:Page>/head", "NULL", TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\ArrayImplementation)
32 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::evaluate("landingPage<TYPO3.Neos:Page>/head", TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\ArrayImplementation)
31 TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\AbstractTypoScriptObject::tsValue("head")
30 TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\ArrayImplementation_Original::evaluate()
29 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::evaluateInternal("landingPage", "Exception")
28 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::render("landingPage")
27 TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\MatcherImplementation_Original::evaluate()
26 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::evaluateInternal("root<TYPO3.TypoScript:Case>/layout<TYPO3.TypoScript:Matcher>", "Exception")
25 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::render("root<TYPO3.TypoScript:Case>/layout<TYPO3.TypoScript:Matcher>")
24 TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\CaseImplementation_Original::renderMatcher("layout")
23 TYPO3\TypoScript\TypoScriptObjects\CaseImplementation_Original::evaluate()
22 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::evaluateInternal("root", "Exception")
21 TYPO3\TypoScript\Core\Runtime_Original::render("root")
20 TYPO3\Neos\View\TypoScriptView_Original::render()
19 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Controller\ActionController_Original::callActionMethod()
18 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Controller\ActionController_Original::processRequest(TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\ActionRequest, TYPO3\Flow\Http\Response)
17 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Dispatcher_Original::dispatch(TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\ActionRequest, TYPO3\Flow\Http\Response)
16 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Dispatcher::dispatch(TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\ActionRequest, TYPO3\Flow\Http\Response)
15 call_user_func_array(array|2|, array|2|)
14 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Dispatcher::Flow_Aop_Proxy_invokeJoinPoint(TYPO3\Flow\Aop\JoinPoint)
13 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AdviceChain::proceed(TYPO3\Flow\Aop\JoinPoint)
12 TYPO3\Flow\Security\Aspect\RequestDispatchingAspect_Original::blockIllegalRequestsAndForwardToAuthenticationEntryPoints(TYPO3\Flow\Aop\JoinPoint)
11 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AroundAdvice::invoke(TYPO3\Flow\Aop\JoinPoint)
10 TYPO3\Flow\Aop\Advice\AdviceChain::proceed(TYPO3\Flow\Aop\JoinPoint)
9 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\Dispatcher::dispatch(TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\ActionRequest, TYPO3\Flow\Http\Response)
8 call_user_func_array(array|2|, array|2|)
7 TYPO3\Flow\Object\DependencyInjection\DependencyProxy::__call("dispatch", array|2|)
6 TYPO3\Flow\Object\DependencyInjection\DependencyProxy::dispatch(TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\ActionRequest, TYPO3\Flow\Http\Response)
5 TYPO3\Flow\Mvc\DispatchComponent_Original::handle(TYPO3\Flow\Http\Component\ComponentContext)
4 TYPO3\Flow\Http\Component\ComponentChain_Original::handle(TYPO3\Flow\Http\Component\ComponentContext)
3 TYPO3\Flow\Http\Component\ComponentChain_Original::handle(TYPO3\Flow\Http\Component\ComponentContext)
2 TYPO3\Flow\Http\RequestHandler::handleRequest()
1 TYPO3\Flow\Core\Bootstrap::run()

HTTP RESPONSE:
[response was empty]
```

Comment: Found in `administration/configuration/` the routes settings and how to display them – they where hidden … and the routes I defined aren't there. So first: how can I activate the configuration to see them permanently? And second is there a hint to load the Routes.yaml-file? I thought it is done automaticly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK. It's necessary to configure the /Configuration/Routes.yaml first with

```
-
  name: 'Vendor Package'
  uriPattern: '<VendorPackageSubroutes>'
  subRoutes:
    'VendorPackageSubroutes':
      package: 'Vendor.Package'
      variables:
        'defaultUriSuffix': '.html'
```

Comment: Is this really required in the main /Configuration/Routes.yaml? If this is a package, how will this be loaded by default, or must this always edited manually?